# Disable AJAX button after nth click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Given I have a model `Post` which can have up to *n* `Comments` (the number is controlled by the Backend) and I have a view which allows to add a `Comment` via a AJAX request. What is the best way to tell the view upon the *nth* request to disable the Add-Comment-Form?

The nth request is successfull so status code should still be 200/201 but the backend already "knows" that the *nth + 1* call will invalidate the `Post`, so i want to somehow tell this to the view so it can take action before the user experiences the (catched) error upon *nth + 1* submit.

By now the backend renders html which is then simply attached to a div in the DOM, with JSON I might add an additional field but then would move the templating to the view again.

If someone has an idea for an elegant solution?

Comment: do you think that a user will add x comments to the post without reloading the page even once? in this case you need to poll the server to check if the limit is already reached. you'll need to poll the server even for checking if there's new comments anyway

Comment: ok Post and Comments was an abstraction for my real models, these are solely controlled by the owning user so yes, he won't have to reload in between

Comment: most likely in the same session, so you suggest to keep track via session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having your server render javascript value for comment count and max comments. Then you can increment the count value in your success function as well as perhaps render the html comment.

Something like

```
 var commentCount = *value from server*;
 var maxComments =*value from server*;

 $('#mybutton').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
             // your code here 
     })
    . success(function (response) {
             // process response
             commentCount ++;
             if( commentCount >= maxComments) 
                  $('#mybutton). prop('disabled', true);
     });
```

Comment: ended up with similar implementation as proposed here

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the "Add comment" button by JavaScript, when it will be "nth + 1". Or remove eventListener from button and change caption to smth like "You reached max comments".

Answer (score 1):

Keep a track of the number of clicks. After the *n* th click, you can change the `disabled` attribute of your button to `true`.

```
$(".myButton").attr("disabled",true);
```

Comment: sure this i might do but it then not feels like the backend is controlling this behaviour since this is then also somewhat coded in the view

Comment: You can store the clicks in your database as a count such that when the user enters the page, the button is disabled if `n` clicks are made. That can happen on page load. I worry about what happens if the user clicks very fast, faster than the database can update, and thus exceeds `n` clicks.

Comment: n+1 is properly handled via backend validation which will result in an error status (no need for extra counter since the association itself provides the needed information)

Comment: but as i think of it you are right, I can just tell the view upon initial rendering what *n* is and let it track this, so it is still fully controlled by the controller but enfored by the view via js